# Math quiz project school

Tags: c#, math

I need to make a  math quiz, and I am stuck.

I am trying to make it so that we can choose a level, generate some random numbers from 1-10, and generate some math symbols also.

We have a `button` and a `combobox`, trying to make 6 levels, and each level needs to generate a random math quiz with random numbers and symbols.

We also need a reset button, and a control button.

I was trying to make this on button:

```
if(combobox_1 == 1)
{
    // than random  here for the labels but i dont know how
}
```

Comment: lets start with what have you tried so far... what worked and what hasn't?

Comment: we changed the the first en last ? to numbers but now we trying to make an array that when you press Start its change to + or -

Comment: Please share the code you have written so far. Stack Overflow is not a place where people do work for you, especially since your requirements are not very clear to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could write this for you, but rather than do that I'll just provide some pointers to get you started and you can go away and put the rest together for yourself.

You can use the Random number generator to generate random numbers:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 10);
```

You can create an array for your math symbols (operators?) using a random number generater selecting an element from an array:

```
var mathSymbols = new[] {'-', '+', '*', '/'};
```

From here you can set levels and construct strings which equate to questions, e.g.

```
random1to10 mathSymbols[random0to3] random1to10 = ?
```

You could get more complex by introducing expressions which sit between parentheses, e.g.

```
random1to10 mathSymbols[random0to3] (random1to10 mathSymbols[random0to3] random1to10) = ?
```

Sounds like fun, school work was never like this for me!

Good luck.

Comment: i need some seriously help here this is what we got so far!!
http://pastebin.com/husbwhzk